# Finding the minimum in a given array using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I don't quite understand the following recursive function. Here's the whole code:

```
public class Minimum {


  static int minimum(int [] array, int z, int k) {
    if (z == k)
      return array[z];

    int s = (z + k) / 2;

    int min1 = minimum(array, z, s);
    int min2 = minimum(array, s+1, k);

    return Math.min(min1, min2);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] array = {4,5,7};

    int min = minimum(array, 0, array.length-1);
    System.out.println(min);
  }
}
```

I'll try to explain my thoughts about how I think it works.

If there is only one element in the array, we return that element (0 == array.length -1, if there is only 1 element)

```
if (z == k)
  return array[z];
```

I understand that we find the mean with the following code, correct?

```
int s = (z + k) / 2;
```

By using the following line, I think we only check the first half of the numbers, (until the mean) in the array?

```
int min1 = minimum(array, z, s);
```

And is the following code used to check the other half of the array?

```
int min2 = minimum(tabela, s+1, k);
```

We now call the Math.min function to get the minimum number in the array

```
return Math.min(min1, min2);
```

Comment: I don't get what you don't understand, you explained every line in code.

Comment: Step 1: Use meaningful variable names, not `z`, `k`, and `s`.

Comment: yeah change the variable names and what exactly is it that you don't understand?

Comment: @sasha Great, before breaking it down I didn't get it at all and even then, I wasn't sure if I'm understanding this correctly since recursion has been a problem since I started programming using python.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the input, but this was the code written by our lecturer, I'll try to keep that in mind when writing my own code.

Comment: @mythic: "Tsk" to the lecturer, then. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets think about this without code to begin with, lets find the minimum of the array `a = [2,4,7,1]`.

Well, using the [divide and conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms) technique we can say the finding the minimum of `a` is the same as finding the minimum of the two halves of the array:

```
min([2,4,7,1]) = min(min([2,4]), min([7,1]))
```

And we can do this *again*

```
min([2,4,7,1]) 
    = min(min([2,4]), min([7,1])) 
    = min(min(min([2]),min([4])), min(min([7]),min([1])))
```

Now we have the termination case to the division, the `min` of a single element is *that element*, break this back out again:

```
min(min(min([2]),min([4])), min(min([7]),min([1])))
    = min(min(2,4), min(7,1))
    = min(2, 1)
    = 1
```

Magic.

So, how does the code you have shown work?

```
static int minimum(int [] array, int z, int k) {
    //if the we are examining the sub array consisting of one element
    if (z == k) {
        //the minimum of the array is that element
        return array[z];
    }
    //find the mid point of the array - also the mean of the two numbers, but that's not really relevant
    int s = (z + k) / 2;
    //find the minimum of the first half, by calling this function
    int min1 = minimum(array, z, s);
    //find the minimum of the second half, by calling this function
    int min2 = minimum(array, s+1, k);
    //return the smaller of the two halves
    return Math.min(min1, min2);
}
```

So, walking through the code with the above example:

```
minimum([2,4,7,1], 0, 3)
```

obviously `z != k`, so we split the array:

```
s = (0 + 3)/2 = 1 //due to integer division
```

so we call:

```
int min1 = minimum([2,4,7,1], 0, 1);
int min2 = minimum([2,4,7,1], 2, 3);
```

Which in turn splits this again, this time to the termination cases.

Comment: Awesome, I kind of understood my code, but now I really understand it. Thank you, highly appreciated.